# Inserting row into google sheet via external WebApp

Tags: google-sheets, google-api

Is it possible to have a web app like so
[image]

insert a row into a google sheet like so
[image]

Answer (score 1):

About your following question,

> Is it possible to have a web app like so

I think that it's yes. As a simple sample script, how about the following sample script?

### Usage:

#### 1. Create Google Spreadsheet.

In this smaple script, Google Spreadsheet and Google Apps Script are used. So, please create a new Google Spreadsheet and open the script editor of Google Spreadsheet.

#### 2. Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor.

```js
function doPost(e) {
  const ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  const obj = { formData: e, spreadsheetId: ssId };
  const res = HtmlFormApp.appendFormData(obj);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ message: "Done", row: res.range.getRow() }));
}
```

#### 3. Install a Google Apps Script library. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/HtmlFormApp)

In order to parse the event object and put it to Spreadsheet, a Google Apps Script library is used.

You can see how to install the library at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/HtmlFormApp#1-install-library).

#### 4. Deploy Web Apps.

The detailed information can be seen at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app). In this case, it supposes that you are using new IDE. Please be careful this.

1. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "New deployment".
2. Please click "Select type" -> "Web App".
3. Please input the information about the Web App in the fields under "Deployment configuration".
4. Please select **"Me"** for **"Execute as"**.

   - This is the importance of this workaround.
5. Please select **"Anyone"** for **"Who has access"**.

   - For testing this script, I thought that this setting might be suitable.
6. Please click "Deploy" button.
7. Copy the URL of the Web App. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
   - You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### 5. Testing:

In order to put the values to the deployed Web Apps, please use the following sample HTML form. Please set your Web Apps URL to `url`.

```html
<form>
  First Name: <input type="text" name="First Name" /><br />
  Last Name: <input type="text" name="Last Name" /><br />
  Date: <input type="date" name="Date" /><br />
  Amount: <input type="number" name=" Amount" /><br />
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="submit" onclick="run(this);return false;" />
</form>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tanaikech/HtmlFormObjectParserForGoogleAppsScript_js/htmlFormObjectParserForGoogleAppsScript_js.min.js"></script>

<script>
  async function run(e) {
    const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"; // Please set your Web Apps URL here.

    const obj = await ParseFormObjectForGAS(e.parentNode, null, null, true);
    fetch(url, { method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify(obj) })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => console.log(res));
  }
</script>
```

- When you open this HTML form using a browser, you can see the HTML form. When you put the values and click the submit botton, the values are sent to Web Apps and they are put to the Spreadsheet.

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".
- This is a simple sample script. So, please modify this for your actual situation.

### References

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [HtmlFormApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/HtmlFormApp)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)